# Javascript How to define multiple variables on a single line?

Tags: javascript

Reading documentation online, I'm getting confused how to properly define multiple JavaScript variables on a single line.

If I want to condense the following code, what's the proper JavaScript "strict" way to define multiple javascript variables on a single line?

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
```

Is it:

```
var a = b = 0;
```

or

```
var a = var b = 0;
```

etc...

Comment: More on multiple assignment: [How does variable assignment work in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509579/320399).  I find this pattern useful inside a closure to expose constructor functions: `var $cls = my.namespace.Foo = function(args){ ... }`

Answer (score 168):

Using Javascript's es6 or node, you can do the following:

```
var [a,b,c,d] = [0,1,2,3]
```

And if you want to easily print multiple variables in a single line, just do this:

```
console.log(a, b, c, d)
```

> 0 1 2 3

This is similar to @alex gray 's answer here, but this example is in Javascript instead of CoffeeScript.

Note that this uses Javascript's [array destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: why not use `console.log(a,b,c,d)` in this case instead? it's shorter and gives the same output

Comment: Another alternative here as @Prince Ahmed's answer demonstrates:
`let {a,b,c,d} = {"a":0,"b":1, "c":2, "d":3}`

Answer (score 102):

You want to rely on commas because if you rely on the multiple assignment construct, you'll shoot yourself in the foot at one point or another.

An example would be:

```
>>> var a = b = c = [];
>>> c.push(1)
[1]
>>> a
[1]
```

They all refer to the same object in memory, they are not "unique" since anytime you make a reference to an object ( array, object literal, function ) it's passed by reference and not value. So if you change just one of those variables, and wanted them to act individually you will not get what you want because they are not individual objects.

There is also a downside in multiple assignment, in that the secondary variables become globals, and you don't want to leak into the global namespace.

```
(function() {  var a = global = 5 })();
alert(window.global) // 5
```

It's best to just use commas and preferably with lots of whitespace so it's readable:

```
var a = 5
  , b = 2
  , c = 3
  , d = {}
  , e = [];
```

Comment: That's really an issue with assigning array references in general, not just with assignment statements as values.

Comment: "So while you can get away with multiple right hand assignments for things like numeric literals"

Comment: @meder, it's an issue with any assignments.  There's nothing special about right hand.

Comment: I meant assignments in general. Edited wording.

Comment: Something to keep in mind with this multiple assignment pattern is that any undeclared assignment, under ES5 Strict Mode, will cause a `ReferenceError` exception... IMO, they should be avoided...

Answer (score 59):

There is no way to do it in one line with assignment as value.

```
var a = b = 0;
```

makes b global.  A correct way (without leaking variables) is the slightly longer:

```
var a = 0, b = a;
```

which is useful in the case:

```
var a = <someLargeExpressionHere>, b = a, c = a, d = a;
```

Comment: "There is no way to use assignment as value without repeating 0." - what do you mean?

Answer (score 57):

Why not doing it in two lines?

```
var a, b, c, d;    // All in the same scope
a = b = c = d = 1; // Set value to all.
```

The reason why, is to preserve the local scope on variable declarations, as this:

```
var a = b = c = d = 1;
```

will lead to the implicit declarations of `b`, `c` and `d` on the window scope.

Comment: This was useful for me because I declare many variables upfront in my program. Now, instead of taking 30+ lines I can use a few lines without sacrificing readability.

Comment: This succinctly clarifies (and improves upon) the accepted answer, it's as simple and reliable and doesn't require unnecessary ES6 destructuring or array methods.

Answer (score 24):

#### Here is the new ES6 method of declaration multiple variables in one line:

```js
const person = { name: 'Prince', age: 22, id: 1 };

let {name, age, id} = person;

console.log(name);
console.log(age);
console.log(id);
```

* **Your variable name and object index need be same**

Comment: That's longer than the OP's question, because it's equivalent to `let { a, b } = { a: 0, b: 0 }`.

Comment: @PrinceAhmend Is it possible to assign variables in same way if they were not new declarations

Answer (score 15):

Specifically to what the OP has asked, if you want to initialize N variables with the same value (e.g. `0`), you can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) and [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to assign to the variables an array of N `0`s:

```js
let [a, b, c, d] = Array(4).fill(0);

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

Answer (score 2):

do this if they have same value

```
let x = y = z = 0
```

otherwise

```
let [x, y, z] = [10, 30, 50]
console.log(x, y, z) // 10 30 50
```

Answer (score 2):

The compressed type of that is here:

```
var a, b = a = "Hi";
```

& for 3 variables:

```
var x, y, z = x = y = "Hello";
```

Hope to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

note you can only do this with Numbers and Strings

you could do...

```
var a, b, c; a = b = c = 0; //but why?

c++;
// c = 1, b = 0, a = 0;
```

Comment: and also booleans, no ?

Comment: @Lah Ezcen Yes on all immutable datatypes I believe

Answer (score -2):

This is completely correct:

```
var str1 = str2 = str3 = "value";
```

And if change one of their value, the value of other variables won't change:

```js
var str1 = str2 = str3 = "value";

/* Changing value of str2 */
str2 = "Hi Web!";

document.write("str1 = " + str1 + " - str2 = " + str2 + " - str3 = " + str3);
```

Comment: You didn't care to read the other warnings about this leading to str2 & str3 being global variables, right?