# Is setting multiple variables in 1 line valid in javascript? (var x=y='value';)

Tags: javascript, variables

This is valid in php:

```
$x=$y='value';
```

This will in esscence set both $x and $y to 'value'.

Is this valid in javascript?

```
var x=y='value';
```

I have tested it in chrome console and it worked as expected, but just wanted to double check before starting to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define multiple variables on a single line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166785/how-to-define-multiple-variables-on-a-single-line)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It only works if the `var y` as been previously **defined**, otherwise `y`will be **global**.

In such case, you better do:

```
var x, y;
x = y = 'value';
```

### Assignments Chaining

**Another antipattern that creates implied globals is to chain assignments as part of a
var declaration. In the following snippet, `a` is local but `b` becomes global, which is
probably not what you meant to do:**

```
// antipattern, do not use
function foo() {
   var a = b = 0;
   // ...
}
```

If you’re wondering why that happens, it’s because of the right-to-left evaluation. First,
the expression `b = 0` is evaluated and in this case b is not declared. The return value of
this expression is `0`, and it’s assigned to the new local variable declared with `var a`. In
other words, it’s as if you’ve typed:

```
var a = (b = 0);
```

If you’ve already declared the variables, chaining assignments is fine and doesn’t create
**unexpected globals**. Example:

```
function foo() {
   var a, b;
   // ...
   a = b = 0; // both local
}
```

*“JavaScript Patterns, by Stoyan Stefanov
(O’Reilly). Copyright 2010 Yahoo!, Inc., 9780596806750.”*

Answer (score 14):

I'm pretty sure that the most readable form is the one that has not been brought up yet:

```
let x = 0, y = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, upvoted!  Unlike the accepted answer, this solution works on `const` as well.

Answer (score 8):

To prevent the y from becoming a global variable, use the following:

```
var x, y = x = 'value';
```

Apparently the declarations are simply evaluated from left to right.

Comment: `var x, y, z = y = x = 'value';` For whatever reasons ;)

Comment: Well ain't this just the cutest thing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is valid in Javascript.

However, after googling the problem, this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166785/javascript-how-to-define-multiple-variables-on-a-single-line) explains some caveats, so use with caution.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not have articles.

Answer (score 0):

When vars have different values you can easily write:

```
var x = 0,
    y = 1,
    ...
    z = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases involving objects and arrays, `Assignments Chaining` is not safe.

This is an example:

```js
    const a = {}
  // Use Assignments Chaining to save some typing.
  a['foo'] = a['bar'] = []

  // I just want to set a['foo'] when some condition meets.
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a['foo'].push({ title: 'hello', number: i / 2 })
  }

  // But you maybe get this unexpected assignment.
  console.log(a['bar']) 
/*
  [
    {
      "title": "hello",
      "number": 0
    },
    {
      "title": "hello",
      "number": 0.5
    },
    {
      "title": "hello",
      "number": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "hello",
      "number": 1.5
    },
    {
      "title": "hello",
      "number": 2
    }
  ]
*/
```