# About Javascript code from Eloquent Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

What means this code: `var entry = arrayName[i], index = 0;`? 
I don't understand what is function this `index = 0`.

Comment: it gives variable index value of 0. Please refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166785/how-to-define-multiple-variables-on-a-single-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shorthand for initializing variables.

```
var entry = arrayName[i], index = 0;
```

is the same as writing

```
var entry = arrayName[i];
var index = 0;
```