# Why a variable defined in shorthand is undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method like this in React:

```
save(){
  let po=pd=idv=false;
  //some logic to set po,pd, and idv true if meets a condition
}
```

Whenever this method is called, it always says "Uncaught ReferenceError : idv is undefined." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using inside function?

Comment: The scope of `let` variables are with in the block in which they are defined

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: In this code, `po` is a local variable. `pd` and `idv` are global.

Comment: i just set them true inside if block

Comment: Possible duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166785/how-to-define-multiple-variables-on-a-single-line/39155732

Comment: duplicate pala otak kau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might solve the problem

```
save() {
 let po,pd,idv;
 po = pd = idv = false;
}
```