# How to create a lot of variables in react by writing little code

Tags: javascript

I want to make a lot of variables like the below code.
I think if I use  the `maps` function it will work, but it does not work.
Could you teach me how to reduce the code?

```
const name = useInput("");
  const area = useInput("");
  const job = useInput("");
  const company = useInput("");
  const school = useInput("");
  const tall = useInput("");
  const body = useInput("");
  const religion = useInput("");
  const smoking = useInput("");
  const blood = useInput("");
  const birthday = useInput("");
  const kakao = useInput("");
  const image1 = useInput("");
  const image2 = useInput("");
  const image3 = useInput("");
  const introduction = useInput("");
```

Comment: What does `useInput` do?  Is it pure function?`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko it is react-apollo-hooks function

https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks

Comment: You can't call hooks in loops.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript How to define multiple variables on a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166785/javascript-how-to-define-multiple-variables-on-a-single-line)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can convert it to array and object

```
const arr = ['name', 'area', etc...];
const obj = {};
arr.forEach(key => {
 obj[key] = useInput(key);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but maybe you could tell the OP how to access obj to access the values entered.

Comment: in future you will be able to use destruction `const { name, area, } = obj;`

Comment: That probably won't work: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

Array(16) please change number according to your variables

```
const [name,area,job,company,school,tall,body,religion,smoking,blood,birthday,kakao,image1,image2,image3,introduction] = Array(16).fill().map(() => useInput(""))
```

Comment: That probably won't work: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html