# How to assign multiple variables on a single line?

Tags: javascript, class, random, variable-assignment

```
class Color {
constructor(red, green, blue) {
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;
}

  generateColor(){
    // this.red, this.green, this.blue = this.randomColor() ???
    return (`Random Color : \n Red : ${this.red}\n Green : ${this.green}\n Blue : 
             ${this.blue}`)
  }

  randomColor() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  }
}
```

How can i make this kind of multiple assignment without using arrays ?

Comment: not sure what you're referring to but perhaps `this = { red, green, blue }`?

Comment: This question is already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166785/javascript-how-to-define-multiple-variables-on-a-single-line

Comment: @Nick " this " is reffering to variables in the constructor method of Color class. its not what im asking but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @JeffreyRam That is for defining multiple variables, not assigning multiple properties

Comment: @JeffreyRam the problem is that red, green, and blue will have the same value

Comment: @MatiasCabral can't reproduce that problem. Can you show use how you're using this class?

Comment: "without using arrays" -- there are no arrays in your code.

Comment: Which assignment are you trying to replace?

Comment: @MatiasCabral It does not have the same value. Refer to my answer for a code snippet and click Run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign three properties of your object with a single line of code use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with `this` as first arg and an object literal as the second.

```js
class Color {
constructor(red, green, blue) {
  this.red = red;
  this.green = green;
  this.blue = blue;
}

  generateColor(){
    // this.red, this.green, this.blue = this.randomColor() ???
    Object.assign(this, {red: this.randomColor(), green: this.randomColor(), blue: this.randomColor()});

    return (`Random Color : \n Red : ${this.red}\n Green : ${this.green}\n Blue : ${this.blue}`)
  }

  randomColor() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  }
}

const colorObj = new Color('55','33','11');

console.log(colorObj.generateColor());
```

Comment: I think what he's asking about is the commented assignment in `generateColor`, not the assignments to `this.XXX`

Comment: inside generateColor() i need to assign a new value to each variable and print it ("Look for the commented line"). BUT i learned something new ! thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer using the same method but in the correct place.

Comment: You're using the same random value for all components of the color. I don't think he wants that.

Comment: @WillD Oh NO :( i thought this may work, but Barmar is right i need different random values.

Comment: @MatiasCabral updated, they will now be three different random values.

Comment: @WillD i think this is the best approach, but it looks like javascript doesn't have that kind of assignment like the commented line. Thanks for your time ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Color {
constructor(red, green, blue) {
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;
}

  generateColor(){
    [this.red, this.green, this.blue] = [this.randomColor(), this.randomColor(), this.randomColor()]
    return (`Random Color : \n Red : ${this.red}\n Green : ${this.green}\n Blue : ${this.blue}`)
  }

  randomColor() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  }
}

const colorObj = new Color('1','1','1');

console.log(colorObj.generateColor());
```