# Object literal root property is undefined when used from within another property's function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

I've been reading for hours and can't seem to find an answer that suits my needs. I don't want to change up the structure at this point, due to the size of the code.  I am trying to find a solution that works from within the structure I've already got in place, if at all possible.

**First, here is a very simplified mock-up of my object literal structure:**

```
NS = 
{
    x: undefined,

    button: undefined,

    fn: 
    {
        root: undefined,

        doSomething: function () 
        {
            var root = this.root,
                x = root.x;       // exception occurs here

            // do something with x
        }
    },

    init: function () 
    {
        var self = this,
            x = self.x,
            button = self.button,
            fn = self.fn,
            fn.root = self;

        x = $("#x");
        button = $("#button");    

        button.on("click", fn.doSomething);
    }
};
```

I know it looks like the declarations under `init()` aren't really needed, but the namespaces can get rather long, so I like to shorten them like that.  This has worked great for me in almost every scenario until I hit this snag.  I know I could fully qualify everything and it should work, but I really don't want to do that due to the aforementioned long namespaces.

My issue is that my root property `x` doesn't keep its value after it was set in the `init()` function when it's being accessed from within another property's function.  You can `console.log(this.x)` from within the `init()` function and it's there.  However, when you click the button and the onClick function tries to declare `x = root.x` it throws:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined*

---

**UPDATE:**

Adding `console.log()` shows that `fn.root.x` is undefined even before the handler is called:

```
init: function () 
{
    var self = this,
        x = self.x,
        button = self.button,
        fn = self.fn,
        fn.root = self;

    x = $("#x");

    console.log(x); // this shows the object
    console.log(fn.root.x); // this throws the undefined exception

    button = $("#button");    
    button.on("click", fn.doSomething);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doSomething is called as an event handler, `this` will be the event target inside the function. So `this.root` will be undefined, and undefined doesn't have any properties, so `root.x` raises an error.

One solution is to fix the value of `this` with [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
button.on("click", $.proxy(fn.doSomething, self));
```

Comment: Very interesting ... i've not looked at $.proxy before. Let me try that.  Do you know if this creates any more overhead than what I'm already trying to do?

Comment: It will create a new function, using Function.prototype.bind if available. But I don't think that will have any performance impact.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't end up working.  Here's the weird thing.  If you `console.log(x)` right after `x = $("#x")`, it's there.  Then right after that if you `console.log(fn.root.x)` it's already undefined.

Comment: That's a different issue: x is a local variable where you're assigning to it; to assign to NS.x you have to use NS.x = ... (there are no pointers in js)

Comment: It's a little tricky in js, but in short: (1) there are no pointers; (2) you always pass/assign by value; (3) when the value you reference is an object, it's actually a reference to that object, and you can share properties (so `var x = {'foo': true}; var y = x; y.foo = false; y.foo === x.foo /* true */; y === x /* true */`) - but if `y = {}`, then `x` will remain untouched. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... that really helps solidify things

Answer (score 0):

Actually, JS objects and arrays are passed by reference. In your example, if x is an object and not `undefined`:

```
NS = {
    x: {},
    button: undefined,
    // etc
};
```

Then in your `init` method you can do something like this and it will work:

```
init: function(){
    var self = this,
        x = self.x;

    x.foo = 'foo!';
    console.log(self.x.foo);  // Logs 'foo!'
}
```

However, in your example, when you assign `x = $('#x')` you are in fact changing only the reference of this local x variable to the newly created jQuery object. What you need to do for your example to work is to make both variables reference the same object:

```
init: function(){
    var self = this,
        x = self.x = $('#x');

    x.on('click', function(){
        console.log('foo!');
    });

    self.x.trigger('click');  // Logs 'foo!'
}
```