# Javascript Variables as Object Pointers

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

I have a question out of curiosity. So I looked into how JS handles variable assignment and I get it. [How does variable assignment work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript)

But the same principle doesn't seem to exhibit itself in the following code I am working on:

```
var temp = playlist1[0];
playlist1[0] = playlist1[1];
playlist1[1] = temp;
```

I know this is a standard way to swap array elements. But if temp is pointing at `playlist1[0]`, and `playlist1[0]`'s contents are changed to `playlist1[1]`'s then how come I don't end up with two `playlist1[1]` values in a row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does variable assignment work in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript)

Comment: I voted this as a duplicate because the answer in the question you linked is the answer to your question.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I think the question is fair since it asks for further clarification on an existing question. The other question is old and probably not monitored anymore.

Comment: Old or no, the answer is the same.

Comment: OP argues that he asked this question to further his understanding of the topic. Upon initial interpretation (not coming from a place of 'knowing already') the linked question does not clearly answer the question. Upon final interpretation (coming from a place of 'knowing already') then the OP sees how the linked question may help; as a reference text and not a learning text. But OP maintains that this question adds value to the linked question and deepens the learning as to avoid a probable misconception of the variable as object pointer concept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not only *variables* are object pointers. *All values* (that are not primitives) are object pointers. So `temp` is an object pointer. `playlist1` is a object pointer to an array object whose elements are object pointers. e.g. `playlist1[0]` is an object pointer, `playlist1[1]` is an object pointer, etc.

> But if temp is pointing at playlist1[0]

This doesn't make sense. `temp` is an object pointer. It points to an object. `playlist1[0]` is not an object; it's an object pointer. `temp = playlist1[0];` makes the object pointer `temp` point to the same object as object pointer `playlist1[0]`.

If you know C, it is equivalent to something like this:

```
Object *playlist1[10];

Object *temp = playlist1[0];
playlist1[0] = playlist1[1];
playlist1[1] = temp;
```

Comment: OP's takeaway: array elements are not objects, they too are pointers to objects. This answered my question and deepened my understanding of the mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

This is consistent with the answer in the referenced question:
You are just changing which object the variable points to - not the data it used to point to. Meaning temp is unaffected by the move to have playlist1[1] point to playlist1[2]. Temp retains the original value it pointed to when playlis1[1] and temp both pointed to it. Only playlist1[1] is updated

Answer (score 0):

Because those are still references to elements in the array and not the elements themselves.  So in the line:

```
playlist[1]=playlist[2]
```

You are not changing anything about temp.  Contrast that with something like (assuming array elements were objects):

```
playlist[1].x=playlist[2].x
```

That is actually assigning the value of the object in the array, and if temp pointed to playlist[1], then temp.x would equal playlist[2].x

Answer (score 0):

say we have  `obj={l1:{l2:[1,2]},}` and we want to address `obj.l1.l2[1]` using an array of levels like `arr=["l1","l2",1]` then :

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'point',{
    value:function(arr){
        var rez=this;
        for(var s in arr){
            rez=rez[arr[s]];
            if(rez === undefined) return undefined;
        }
        return rez;
    }
});
```

So after defining "point" method (which is not enumerable to mess up everithing) we can use

```
obj.point(arr)
```

to get value 2