# Variable population and callbacks in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I've come across [a presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/cacois/nodejs-patterns-for-discerning-developers) (slide 50-51), where the author gives an example on how to batch the callbacks of 10000 identical file reads in Node.

```
// Batching wrapper around the real FS.readFile
var requestBatches = {};
function batchingReadFile(filename, callback) {
  // First check to see if there is already a batch
  if (requestBatches.hasOwnProperty(filename)) {
    requestBatches[filename].push(callback);
    return;
  }

  // Otherwise start a new one and make a real request
  var batch = requestBatches[filename] = [callback];
  FS.readFile(filename, onRealRead);

  // Flush out the batch on complete
  function onRealRead() {
    delete requestBatches[filename];
    for (var i = 0, l = batch.length; i < l; i++) {
      batch[i].apply(null, arguments);
    }
  }
}

// Request the same resource 10,000 times at once
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  batchingReadFile(__filename, onRead);
}

function onRead(err, file) {
  if (err) throw err;
}
```

As a newbie node developer there is one thing in this example I just don't get how the variable `callbacks` is set to an array containing just one callback function (`var callbacks = requestBatches[filename] = [callback];`), yet how can it contain 10000 callback functions in the `onRead` function?

I get that the `onRead` function is put on the event queue and isn't called until the `batchingReadFile` function has been called all 10000 times, but still, how does the other callback functions end up in `callbacks`?

Am I missing something very obvious? If so, please be gentle and point it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed the code;

```
if (filename in requestBatches) {
    requestBatches[filename].push(callback);

    return;
}
```

... this ensures that successive calls to `batchedReadFile`, with the same filename, get their callbacks added to the array which *starts off* at size 1.

By the time the `onRead` function executes, the array *will* contain 1,000 callback functions.

Comment: Yes, they are added to the "requestBatches" variable, but it's the "callbacks" varaible that being used in "onRead".

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I missed/ignored/forgot that javascript uses pointers. This question got me on the right track:
[How does variable assignment work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript)