# Any way to assign a variable (not an object property) another variable's value by reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment

So, here's what I need:

```
var a = 5;
var b = a;
a = 6;
alert(b) // I want this to alert 6 not 5
```

I've seen questions like [How does variable assignment work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509579/1117796), answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/509614/1117796 and posts like http://hpyblg.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/simulating-pointers-in-javascript/. I do NOT want to use objects/hashes/dictionaries or whatever else you want to call them. I want this done with plain variables containing plain primitive values. Something like the PHP assignment by reference: `$b = &$a;`. Is it at all possible? Anything that comes near to it?

Comment: No, as you saw, this isn't possible.

Comment: you may do this by writing a function of reassigning 'b' ; aequal(a){b=a;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that isin't possible to pass simple values as reference in JavaScript.

However JavaScript is a flexible language and you could possibly implement something similar using `Object.defineProperty` by providing setters and getters that will all work with the same variable. That could work for `global` variables however, there's no way to completely mimic this behaviour. For instance, since you can't get a reference to the execution scope of functions, you would not be able to emulate this concept for variables declared inside functions.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible as of ECMA Script 5.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. And its a boon that this is not allowed in JavaScript.