# Change array variable inside Javascript object literals

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object

An example of below is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/valgaze/se9bmx7t/

Big question: Why does clearing an array "break" the relationship between an array and that array's reference in an object literal in Javascript?

Imagine we have an array stored in a variable and we have object literal with a reference to that array as one of the properties of the object. When we use any of the typical array methods (push, pop, shift, etc) on the array, the object literal gets updated with the result. And similarly if we update the array by accessing it from the object literal then the array variable is updated.

Ex. **Updating the object updates the array (and vice versa)**

```
var myArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

var myObject = {key1:"value1", key2:myArray}

//Array is updated, so object is updated
myArray.push("item4"); //Update the array

console.log(myObject.key2); //Object's array updated with new pushed value

//Object is updated, so array is updated
myObject.key2.push("item5"); //myArray is updated with the item5
console.log(myArray); //Array updated with item5
```

Question: **Why does "clearing" the array break the binding/coupling on the array reference in the object?**

```
    //[...] continued from first block above

    myArray = ["muahahah, everything is wiped out"];
    console.log("myArray", myArray); //Returns ["muahahah, everything is wiped out"]
    console.log("myObject.key2", myObject.key2); //Returns the original items 1-5 

    //If we clear out the array via the object, the array does get updated
    myObject.key2 = ["cleared the array from object"];
    console.log("myArray", myArray); //returns ["cleared array"]
    console.log("myObject.key2", myObject.key2); //returns ["cleared array"]
```

There must be something going on with manipulating an array like this: myArray = ["wiped values"];

Comment: you broke the reference by assigning a new object (array) instead of manipulating the existing one

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does variable assignment work in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not "clearing" the array, you're assigning a new value to your variable. The original array still exists (as a reference inside the other object), but now `myArray` points to a different array reference.