# Is there a way to add "subproperties" to a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, variables, properties, getter

I was asking myself if there is a way to add something like a *subproperty* to a variable. Here is an example of what I want to achive:

```
var variable = 5;
variable.property = "what ever...";
console.log(variable); //outputs 5
console.log(variable.property); //outputs "what ever..."
```

(The data types aren't important...)

Is there maybe a way to achive this using getters or Proxys, and does my variable need to be an object or not?

Hopefully you can help and there is a way to do this :)

Comment: you can set variable as { value: 5 } initially, then use variable.value to output 5

Comment: @Brian Yeah, but that's not what I want...

Comment: If the variable is not a primitive type (e.g. `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`), then that will work (except that your second `var` keyword is not appropriate.)  Everything else descends from `Object`, where this is normal. ([There are exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), BTW, but probably not important here.)  It might not always be a good idea, but it should work.  With primitives, you will be able to set the value, but it immediately disappears.

Comment: Not directly on a primitive, though you can modify Number.prototype, this is also unadvisable if this question is for anything more than curiosity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ad-hoc properties to any variable which points to an `Object`. You should also read up on `prototype` if you're interested in using class-like objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

However, your example uses the number 5, which is a **Primitive**. You cannot assign properties to Primitives: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509780/71906