# Undeclared object variable showing undefined instead of ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var obj = {a : 2};
console.log(obj.b); //prints undefined
console.log(b);      //ReferenceError
```

Here both obj.b and  b are not defined. Can anyone explain the reason behind the different outputs?

Comment: obj.b is a property of obj, which doesn't exist (hence undefined), b is a variable that doesn't exist (hence reference error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does variable assignment work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript)

Comment: You should take a look around, plenty of answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript)

Comment: @Ian I checked that answer before posting this question. That answer never really explained the different outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a missing property, the second is a missing variable.

See also the difference here:

```js
console.log(window.b);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks @trincot

Answer (score 0):

`obj.b` is `undefined` cause he don't exist in your object and `var b` does not exist too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the first part work by this

```
var obj = {a : 2};
console.log(obj.a); //Your property `b` was not defined or you typed `b` instead of `a`
```

..and the second part by this

```
var b = 3;
console.log(b);// `b` was not defined at all
```

Explanations in the comments

Comment: I intentionally typed b in place of a. I was trying to find out why obj.b and b behaved differently.